# Uploading/Downloading IFC model from AWS server to our Unity application

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, ifc, architect

My requirements in short.

1. I need to upload an IFC building model from mobile in our unity application.
2. Need to convert it to .GLB format.
3. Need to upload/Download the .GLB models  from AWS server based on user stored models.

These are my requirements, to achieve this i have gone through some tutorial stated that, we need to convert the .GLB to .GLTF format which gives in lesser size. Please suggest me any workaround how i can achieve my requirement.

Comment: Your requirement is short, but you'll see the actually programming is challenging. After upload, use IfcConvert to go from IFC to DAE, than run COLLADA2GLTF to go to either glb or gltf. These processes can take some time to run, so you'll need to run them in a queue system, separate from your browser/backend logic.

Comment: Yes Maarten,It is an time taking process. Can you please tell me what is the technical approach which i need to follow to speed up the process.